# SQL Server - Pivot data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to transpose data from last two column in SQL table from this layout:

[image]

into lay out where im going to have one line with last two column to be "fw" and "bw" with counts values underneath as on the layout below:

[image]

I understand that i have to use Pivot and i have been trying to follow few tutorials and few post here on stack-overflow but i cant seem to make it work. 
Any hint or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below

```
select * from tablename
pivot
(
  sum(counts) for label in ([fw],[bw])
) as pv
```

Comment: this was quick and amazing. Thank you so much.